# How to Compute Eigenvalue of a Hessenberg Matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

When I do the Givens Rotation and end up with a upper triangular matrix, I can easily get the eigenvalues by looking at the main diagonal, but these values aren't the same as when I just use numpy.linalg.eigvals on the original matrix, and i can't really understand why

In another situation, when I do the decomposition using my QR piece of code and using linalg.qr,i get the same absolute values, but some of them are negative, in the latter, and I also don't understand the reason behind it

All I need is to compute the eigenvalues of a Hessenberg matrix

Comment: I think this question would benefit from some examples, as it's not very clear what's going on from your words alone

Comment: You shouldn't expect the eigenvalues of $A=QR$ and $R$ to be the same.

Comment: Lessons learned: 1) Transformations other than similarity transformations do not preserve eigenvalues. 2) QR factorization is not unique: $1\times 1$ matrix $A=1$ has two real QR factorizations $A=1\times 1$ and $A=(-1)\times(-1)$. 3) QR factorization is not [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm).